# Failed to deploy on Heroku, Unknown error message for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

**Hi** there; I have built a application on Node. Its operation is perfect, but when doing the deployment in Heroku it gives me this error

It tells me something about the path and favicon.ico, but I can't find a fault about that in particular. Please I need a little help. Thank you very much in advance

EDIT1: My Varibles; code and Heroku config

EDIT2

```
"scripts": {
        "desarrollo": "concurrently \"npm run dev \" \"npm run watch\" ",
        "dev": "nodemon ./index.js",
        "start": "node index.js",
        "watch": "webpack --w --mode development"
      }
```

I have also tried:

```
"start": "node ./index.js",
```

Maybe the error comes out there, I'm almost a novice in Heroku

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server has to listen on the port specified by the `PORT` environment variable, it can't just listen on any port it wants. Basically, in your code you want to listen on `process.env.PORT`.

Comment: Hi Aplet123; These are my variables both in heroku and in the code; if something is missing you tell me; I have put them in EDIT1. If I have not misunderstood I have to change the name of the variable. The question I have is which of the 2? In variables.env or in the main Index.js, in EDIT 1 is a capture of my index.js too.

Comment: Does your code actually listen on the port in the `PORT` variable?

Comment: In the screenshots you can see the ports and their configuration as well as the variables. To be able to read variables from variables.env, is process.env necessary? Or so I thought. I have the BD_ * for the database and the PORT AND HOST for the server. The question is in my index.js I am afraid to rename the variables? thank you very much for your support

Comment: This code should be working judging from the screenshots.

Comment: Oh my friend, I've been around for hours and I have no idea where to go to get rid of the problem ...
heroku hates me

Comment: Make sure your `package.json` has the correct start script in it.

Comment: I leave you code so you can see how the script is,Thanks, thanks, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210518/discussion-between-lekanda-and-aplet123).